# How do I perform an action when a button in a WinJS ContentDialog is clicked?

Tags: winjs

I am new to WinJS, and I want to make a `ContentDialog` that will contain a textbox, for entering an API key and Submit and Cancel buttons. When the ok button is clicked, a method should be triggered that will do a bit of validation and then persist the data. I have been trying to find out how I can add an event listener to one of the `ContentDialog` buttons but cannot find out how. I have been googling, and found:

http://try.buildwinjs.com/#contentdialog

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn904229.aspx

https://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/displaying-dialogs-in-winjs/

None of these hint on how to accomplish this. Can this be done? If so how?

Comment: use can use standard dom apis. `element.querySelector()` to get to the button and `buttonElement.addEventListener('click')` to register your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

in your JS code add:

```
    var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    button1.addEventListener("click", button1Click, false)
```

'button1' is the id of the HTML element.
'button1Click' is your js function to perform the action.